# How do I toggle the view between perspective/orthographic with out a numpad in 2.8?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, orthographic

In 2.8, I'm trying not to use the *emulate numpad* option since that replaces the [1,2,3] selection modes in edit mode.

So far the '~' pie menu is pretty quick for switching views, but there's no option for changing the perspective. It looks like the action still only responds to Numpad 5, is there no other way without emulating the numbers?

Comment: Please note the candidate answer was using 2.78.  So I will not know if the candidate answer is useful.

Comment: What about the small *Gizmo* on the top right corner of the 3D View to switch toggle?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 addons bundled with Blender called UI Pie Menu Official or alternatively 3D Viewport Pie Menus (for both 2.79 and 2.8). When enabled they provide list of menus you can call through pie menu, View Numpad Pie as one of them. Both of them have Persp/Ortho switch, though in second-level menu (first you need to hover over View Menu and click it, then click to execute perspective switch).

[image]

Depending on the addon perspective switch will be either under another level of pie menu or submenu of the currently chosen pie menu item.
Only nuance is that in 2.8 position of items in pie menus changed, so that in 2.79 View Menu is on the left, in 2.8 - on the right. If you use both versions you might need to adapt to that.

Comment: Thanks! I tried them both, but it's not great that it will override the Q favorites menu, and you also can't trigger the submenu by releasing the hotkey (like the first level in the menu). Maybe this prevents other complications, it just doesn't feel as fast. I guess this switching just isn't baked in without numpad, but maybe it's not as commonly used as I thought.

Comment: @Forby I did mention that perspective switch isn't on the first-level menu; likely it was considered as not so often used function. I don't think there's any easy way to not emulate numpad *and* use Blender without numpad which always wasn't so much user-friendly. While you can remap Favourites menu to something other than Q, further customizing is likely possible only either with writing addon with pie menu where Persp switch is first level or maybe using some paid solutions like Gesture Ops etc (not sure they provide this though)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

See the numpad setting in User Prefences. Image above.

[image]

User preferences showing a change from numpad 5 to regular 5 for the

orthogonal perspective switch

---

The [View] menu allows you to switch as well.

If you are willing to give up some rarely used [View] keystroke such as

<kbd>5</kbd>  Layer Switch

you may use User Preferences window to do assign a keyboard short cut as shown above

By searching here at BSE you will probably find a tutorial on User Preferences.  This candidate answer is to get you exploring quickly.

Lastly I have an inexpensive separate usb keypad which serves left hand needs.  You might investigate.

Comment: Yeah you could customize that, but it will conflict with the default _Hide Collection_ shortcut in object mode, as well as others. I was hoping this keybinding had made it into a usable default option that I had missed somewhere. Thanks. (Edit: Also, I'm referencing 2.8. This looks like 2.7)